# Enabling the telnet client for all Windows 7 PCs on a domain

Tags: windows-7, telnet

The telnet client is disabled by default in Windows 7. I would like to enable the telnet client for all Windows 7 PCs in our domain. I know how to enable it manually:

- Start
- Control Panel
- Programs And Features
- Turn Windows features on or off
- Check Telnet Client
- Hit OK

How can I do this for all Windows 7 PCs in the domain? All the Windows 7 PCs are in a separate OU.

Can this be enabled by a registry setting that I can apply to all Windows 7 PCs?

Can it be done by a Group Policy?

Comment: To whomever voted to move this to superuser, questions regarding group policy definitely belong here. Just because it is about putting some software on a client PC, doesn't mean it belongs on superuser.

Comment: @Sam The words "Group Policy" doesn't mean that this question must be here. In that case, the words "registry setting" will mean that this must belong to SU. And as I know, one of the shortest ways solve this is using CMD and dism (not GPO or registry)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating a GPO and linking it to the OU where your Windows 7 PCs are.

Create a script (e.g. \\domain.com\netlogon\enable-telnet-client.cmd) with the following command in it:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

Assign that script as a computer startup script in your GPO.

Comment: Does the "/online" word mean that the PC will need connection to internet?

Comment: No. DISM is used to modify deployment images or the O/S that's currently running. /online means "please do this in this O/S, not on an image file." See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744382(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can not. GPO's dont install / uninstall windows features.

You could roll out a MSI package (software install) the shells out the proper command line to install the telnet client, though. And put that into the group policy of the appropriate OU(s).

Comment: You don't need an MSI package to run a simple command. Batch files still have their place in 2010. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but you need elevated priviledges ;) Normal users may not be able to.

Comment: You assign it as a computer startup script, you don't ask users to run it manually.

Comment: yeah, ok - that makes sense.